# Foundation Framework - Issues with Tables

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

(Custom WordPress theme using JointsWP and Foundation 6.2.1)

On the following page (http://indianashrm.wpengine.com/chapters/), I have two tables of data and neither is stacking on smaller devices and the class .unstriped isn't work either.  The .hover class is working though.

Here is my code for the first table (I'm using a custom post type for the data).  Any ideas why the table isn't stacking and the stripes aren't removed?

```
<?php
$args = array (
'post_type'     => 'shrm_local_chapter',
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_status'       => 'publish',
'order'         => 'ASC',
'orderby'           => 'chapter_location'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<h2>Local Chapters</h2>
<p>Scroll down to obtain contact information for your nearest local Indiana SHRM Chapter. Information on how to join that chapter can be found on their local web page.</p>
<table class="stacked unstriped hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="50%">Name</th>
      <th width="50%">Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$shrm_location = get_field( "chapter_location" );
$shrm_url = get_field( "chapter_url" );
$shrm_name = get_the_title();

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td><a href="'.$shrm_url.'">'.$shrm_name.'</a></td>';
echo '<td>'.$shrm_location.'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class for a "Stacked" table is `.stack` rather than `.stacked` (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/table.html)

It looks like you're css file doesn't include the "unstriped" class (http://indianashrm.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/indianashrm/vendor/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css?ver=4.7.2) (maybe this is version 4.7.2 of the CSS and not 6.2.1?) so you would have to create your own version or upgrade the CSS file:

```
table.unstriped tbody {
    background-color: #[your std background colour here];
}
table.unstriped tbody tr {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1; // your border colour, this is the stock colour
    background-color: #[your std background colour here];
}
```

Comment: Crap, I had the wrong class name for stack...  !@#$%^&

Comment: I updated to the latest version of Foundation and that fixed the striped issue.  The version included in the JointsWP install indicates 6.2.1 but the unstriped class is not in the file. Not sure why that is and really not sure why I didn't do a search for the class...I took it for granted.  Thank you for stepping up and helping.